# How to generate several random numbers included in a range and whose evolution is in a range in percent in PHP?

Tags: php, random

How to generate several random numbers included in a range and whose evolution is in a range in percent?

The goal is to generate random numbers while avoiding significant discrepancies.

i tried this code but with php 7.4, the random number only increases until I get a fatal error

```
$min=400; // starting value
$max = 600; // starting value

for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) 
{
    $nb = random_int($min, $max);

    echo $nb . "\n";

    $percentage_min = random_int(0, 10);
    $percentage_max = random_int(10, 20);

    $min = floor($nb-($nb * $percentage_min)/100);

    $max = floor($nb+($nb * $percentage_max)/100);
}
```

Comment: @Cid the evolution is in a range in percent min and max

Comment: I suppose, $percentage is not defined and will be interpreted as zero by PHP. So Multiplying anything by zero is zero! Zero divided by 100 is also zero.

Comment: @t's just an editing error, I corrected my post

Comment: The result is not 0 if you fix the $percentage to $percentage_min as stated above.

Comment: After several hundred iterations the number overflows the maximum size and errors: *Uncaught TypeError: random_int() expects parameter 2 to be int, float given ...* `random_int(7.3019726629039E+18, 9.3433843751136E+18)`

Comment: Indeed but with php 7.4, the random number only increases until I get a fatal error

Comment: @CD001 yes, is the problem now

Comment: That's (probably) as far as you can go. If you put `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` somewhere in your script you'll probably see `9223372036854775807`. Where your sequence dies, the next *max* value could be in excess of `9600000000000000000` which is simply too big a number for PHP to deal with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
$min=0; // starting value
$max = 600; // starting value

$min_absolute = 100;
$max_absolute = 1000;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 2000; $i++) 
{
    if($max > $max_absolute)
    {
        $min = $min_absolute;
        $max = random_int($min_absolute, $max_absolute);
    }

    $nb = random_int($min, $max);

    echo $nb . "\n";

    $percentage_min = random_int(0, 10);
    $percentage_max = random_int(10, 20);

    $min = floor($nb-($nb * $percentage_min)/100);
    $max = floor($nb+($nb * $percentage_max)/100);
}
```

EDIT: It's funny to see anonymous hypocrites voting negatively about a problem and its solution which they don't understand

Comment: Not my downvote, but some code along with *"Here is the solution"* doesn't explain what was wrong, what changed and why. And is not useful for future readers